# how to execute SQL code separatly in SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator Generates method?

Tags: entity-framework-6

I want to run an SQL script after each new table created through Entity Framework.

I created an override for 'CreateTableOperation' like this:

```
protected override void Generate(CreateTableOperation createTableOperation)
{
    string tenantID = "tenantID";
    base.Generate(createTableOperation);
    //If the table contain the column "tenantID",
    if ((from x in createTableOperation.Columns
         where x.Name == tenantID
         select x).Any()
    )
    {
        //Add the Security Policies for this table
        using (var writer = Writer())
        {
            writer.WriteLine("ALTER SECURITY POLICY rls.tenantAccessPolicy ");
            //Note: dbo. is already part of the .Name, don't add it manually before .Name
            writer.WriteLine($"ADD FILTER PREDICATE rls.fn_tenantAccessPredicateWithSuperUser([{tenantID}]) ON [{createTableOperation.Name}], ");
            writer.WriteLine($"ADD BLOCK PREDICATE rls.fn_tenantAccessPredicateWithSuperUser([{tenantID}]) ON [{createTableOperation.Name}] ");
            Statement(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say I create a new class 'TEST'.
The problem is when I run my **Update-Database** in the Package Manager Console, the SQL is executed in one big block and create an error because the table is not yet created and I'm trying to get the table.name **Package Manager result after Update-Database:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST] (
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [NameTEST] [nvarchar](max),
    [TenantID] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.TEST] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
)
ALTER SECURITY POLICY rls.tenantAccessPolicy 
ADD FILTER PREDICATE rls.fn_tenantAccessPredicateWithSuperUser([tenantID]) ON [dbo.TEST], 
ADD BLOCK PREDICATE rls.fn_tenantAccessPredicateWithSuperUser([tenantID]) ON [dbo.TEST]
```

*Cannot find the object "dbo.TEST" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.*
Is there a way to break between the **base.Generate(createTableOperation);** and my **Statement(writer);**? (I already tried multiple things with 'GO' without much success). Or is it that I'm not supposed to put code in that method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution/documentation to separate the code/batch SQL in `Generate(CreateTableOperation createTableOperation).`

What I did instead was to

- generate dynamic SQL scripts in the `Generate(CreateTableOperation createTableOperation)` method

  ```
      /// <summary>
      /// Generate dynamically named .sql file for CREATE and DROP Security Policies (Row-Level Security (Company can't see/insert data of another company))
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="createTableOperation">Default parameter that comes with the override method.</param>
      protected override void Generate(CreateTableOperation createTableOperation)
      {
          base.Generate(createTableOperation);
      string fullFolderPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "..\\Migrations\\SQLscripts\\SecurityPolicies");

      //Remove the schema for the dynamic creation of the .sql filename else it throw an exception: 
      int indexOfDot = createTableOperation.Name.IndexOf(".");
      indexOfDot++; //Because it's 0 base, add 1 char
      string tableNameWithoutSchema = (indexOfDot < 0) ? createTableOperation.Name : createTableOperation.Name.Remove(0, indexOfDot);

      string filePathCreate = Path.Combine(fullFolderPath, $"CreateSecurityPolicies_{tableNameWithoutSchema}.sql");
      string filePathDrop = Path.Combine(fullFolderPath, $"DropSecurityPolicies_{tableNameWithoutSchema}.sql");

      //If .sql files doesn't exists, create them
      if (!File.Exists(filePathCreate))
      {
          using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePathCreate, true))
          {
              sw.WriteLine("ALTER SECURITY POLICY rls.tenantAccessPolicy");
              //Note: Don't concatenate 'dbo.{}' because 'createTableOperation.Name' already include 'dbo'
              sw.WriteLine($" ADD FILTER PREDICATE rls.fn_tenantAccessPredicateWithSuperUser(CompanyID) ON {createTableOperation.Name},");
              sw.WriteLine($" ADD BLOCK PREDICATE rls.fn_tenantAccessPredicateWithSuperUser(CompanyID) ON {createTableOperation.Name}");
              sw.WriteLine("GO");
              sw.Close();
          }
      }

      if (!File.Exists(filePathDrop))
      {
          using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePathDrop, true))
          {
              sw.WriteLine("ALTER SECURITY POLICY rls.tenantAccessPolicy");
              sw.WriteLine($" DROP FILTER PREDICATE ON {createTableOperation.Name},");
              sw.WriteLine($" DROP BLOCK PREDICATE ON {createTableOperation.Name}");
              sw.WriteLine("GO");
              sw.Close();
          }
      }


  }
  ```
- Then, with my SQL scripts in a folder, add it manually to my solution.
- Add-Migration just to run my SQL script by adding code into the empty (up-to-date) migration class.

  ```
  public override void Up()
  {
      string sqlFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "..\\Migrations\\SQLscripts\\CreateSecurityPolicies_Client.sql");
      string sqlText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(sqlFilePath);
      Sql(sqlText);
  }

  public override void Down()
  {
      string sqlFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "..\\Migrations\\SQLscripts\\DropSecurityPolicies_Client.sql");
      string sqlText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(sqlFilePath);
      Sql(sqlText);
  }
  ```

This is the best I can come up with for the moment. I hope it can helps other EntityFramework programmers!